# configure: error: could not find a working compiler, see config.log for details

Tags: ios, cross-compiling

I am trying to port gmp library to ios.
I set all the variables, all the paths to compilers, libraries, SDKs in my script.
All are valid and existing.
All happiness ends with

```
configure: error: could not find a working compiler, see config.log for details
```

config.log contains an error, that `int main(){return 0;}' is not compiled.
This script worked for a couple of libs all ready.
Is that because of arm-apple compiler?

What can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone will ever need answer to this:
As far as I remember, I handled this error by defining the host=arm-apple-darwin and flags (ld and cc) with includedir and libdir to configure parameters.